# How do you get data from a server(Magento) via Ruby and then pass this data into html page in CSV format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, magento, csv

I am trying to learn ruby and my task is first get the data from meganto server via ruby and then i have to past or post all data in to html csv format.

it will be great help if someone help me to give this type of code.

Comment: Try these two links http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap-api-index.html  and  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest-api-index.html

Comment: I think you can accomplish this using SOAP or RESP request to Magento